# "Could not find "store" in either the context or props" I'm getting this error while trying simple react-redux code

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

This is my booklist container

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';


class BookList extends Component{
  renderList(){
    return this.props.books.map((book)=>{
      return(
        <li key={book.title}>{book.title}</li>
      );
    });
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <ul>
       {this.renderList()}
      </ul>
    )
  }
} 

function mapStateToProps(state){
  return{
    books : state.books
  };    
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(BookList);
```

This is my app.js file

```
  import React from 'react';
  import { Component } from 'react';
  import BookList from '../containers/book-list';

  export default class App extends Component{
    render(){
      return(
        <div>
        <div>React simple App</div>
        <BookList/>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
```

This is my index.js file in Reducers folder

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import BooksReducer from './reducer_books';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  books:BooksReducer
});

export default rootReducer;
```

This is my main index.js file which renders app component on

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './components/app';
import './index.css';

ReactDOM.render(
   <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

This is my books reducer

```
export default function () {
  return [
    {title: 'AAA1'},
    {title: 'BBB2'},
    {title: 'CCC3'},
    {title: 'DDD4'},
  ]
}
```

Please tell me where I am wrong.

Comment: i think, you forgot to specify the `Provider store={store}`, add that it will work, check this for reference: http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/ExampleTodoList.html

Comment: Is it also necessary to call `super(props)` inside a `constructor()` class method in the first file to get access to the `books` piece of state from the Redux store?

Comment: Okay @MayankShukla , but where I should add that?

Comment: you need to render the `App` inside the `Provider`, check this link: http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/ExampleTodoList.html

Comment: @MayankShukla, Okay. I'll check the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `store` and enclose your components within a `Provider` like

```
import {createStore} from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import RootReducer form '/path/to/rootreducer';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './components/app';
import './index.css';
const store = createStore(RootReducer);

ReactDOM.render(
   <Provider store={store}>
       <App />
   </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Glad to help :)